# Regex for a filename

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I check if a filename matches a wildcard pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652037/how-do-i-check-if-a-filename-matches-a-wildcard-pattern)

In the program that I am doing, the user has two inputs.

> Input 1 = the filename.
>  Input 2 = the flagFilePattern
>
> ex. 1
>  Input 1 = file1.xml or file25.xml or file_123.xml
> Input 2 = file*.xml
>  Result (all files should match based on the
> pattern(Input 2)
>
> ex. 2
>  Input 1 = file1.xml.done
>  Input 2 = file*.xml
> Result (the file should not match based on the pattern, because .xml
> was not found at the last of the filename).

Question, what should be my regular expression based on the example above?
Note: my code is in C#

Comment: -1 It is unclear what you want to validate, it is unclear if the input2 is dynamic, it is unclear if input2 should always be a filename with the xml-extension and it is unclear why you want to use a regex for the task rather than just validate if the file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `input 2` can be a valid regular expression. All you need to do would be to add the `^` and `$` anchors, these will allow your regex engine to specifically match that pattern, so in your case, you could do something like so:

```
 String input2 = "file*.xml";
        Regex regex = new Regex("^" + input2.Replace(".", "\\.").Replace("*",".*") + "$");
        String input1 = "file_123.xml";
        String input3 = "file_123.xml.done";

        System.Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(input1));
        System.Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(input3));
        System.Console.ReadLine();
...
```

The `.` is a special character in regex so it needs to be escaped. The second `replace` statement adds a `.` which means any character infront of the `*` operator which means or or more repetitions of. The code above yields `True` and `False` respectively.

EDIT: As pointed above, you will need to escape more characters depending on your scenario.

EDIT 2: The code below should take care of escaping any string which is part of the regular expression language. In your case, this also means the `*` operator. I used the `Regex.Escape` method the escape all the characters which might have a special regex meaning and then used the usual `replace` to get the `*` back on track.

```
            String input2 = "file*.xml";
            input2 = Regex.Escape(input2);  //Yields file\\*\\.xml
            input2 = input2.Replace("\\*", ".*");  //Yields file.*\\.xml
            Regex regex = new Regex("^" + input2 + "$");
            String input1 = "file_123.xml";
            String input3 = "file_123.xml.done";

            System.Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(input1));
            System.Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(input3));
            System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: wrong here because "*" matches in his demo SOME chars but in regex only ONE without quantifier...

Comment: @TheHe: Yes you where right, it should be fixed now.

Comment: so TheHe do you mean that it will work if i use .Replace("*", "[A-Za-z0-9*]) instead?

Comment: wow. thanks guys, i will try this immediately.

Comment: @TimPietzcker don't get on our nerves and PLEASE provide a 100% complete answer if you KNOW how to do, instead of fighting against us, who want to help ;)
we're waiting to see an 100%-answer...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes I know about that and I agree with you in what you are saying. I tried to point that out in the last segment of my answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I have tried to make yet another change to my answer, with my limited experience, I do not think that there is a better answer than this involving regular expressions.

Comment: I think if you add `input2 = input2.Replace("\\?", ".");`, then the result will actually be quite OK.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Can you please explain why?

Comment: So the other glob metacharacter `?` is handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

just use input2 and transform that to a correct pattern like

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\A" + (args[1].Replace(".", @"\.").Replace("*", ".*")) + @"\Z");
```

Comment: This is incomplete at best and misleading at worst. There are many other regex metacharacters that you need to escape, and you're not handling `?` at all.

Comment: from my point of view - he just want to use "*" as glob-selector and "?" and other metachars are not very common in normal filenames...

Comment: in addition -- in his examples the names are clear and not very "problematic"

Comment: `?` is a glob metacharacter. And how do you know the filenames don't contain parentheses etc.?

Comment: i don't know that - just provided an answer which completly matches the example above... guy - i know what you're talking about, but that's not the question.

Comment: Nice of you to provide an answer that allows the asker to shoot himself in the foot only because he hasn't thought of the relevant test cases yet.

Comment: nice to shoot an replier because he hasn't thought of ALL and MAYBE not question-relevant aspects which weren't pointed out in the question ;)
c'mon...

Comment: The point of answering a question is not to provide a solution for exactly the test cases the author of the question has thought of yet, but to solve a problem. A solution like this one gives regular expressions a bad name. See the duplicate question I linked to for what a real answer should look like in my opinion.

Comment: we solved EXACTLY this problem and @npinti pointed out futures problems like a charm.
we're not here to TOTALLY think for the authors - just solve a "problem" and let him go alone...
kind of "learning"... if he will have problems again with the solution, he will ask again!?

Answer (score -1):

if `input 2` is always a valid Regex, you can use following code:

```
String regex = input2;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); 

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input1);
```

Comment: Input2 isn't a valid regex in the example (well, it's valid but it doesn't work as intended). It looks rather like a glob pattern

Comment: Thanks for correcting. This link may help visitors: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/what-is-the-difference-between-regular-expressions-and-globbing-828589/