# How do I get a list of files in c# from a directory path which contains wildcards?

Tags: c#, glob

Given a path c:\someFolder\**\*.exe. How can I get a list of files using this directory path. I know that one could use `Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)` but this only works when there are no wildcard characters in directoryPath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: [How to implement glob in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398518/how-to-implement-glob-in-c)