# How to add contents on directory into a ListBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to grab the contents of a directory and display each one, on a seperate row of ListBox, the code I have so far is:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"folder");
    foreach (string path in filePaths)
    {
        listBox2.Items.AddRange(path + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, fine.  Do you have a question?

Comment: You should name your controls.

Comment: Note to my answer.You are iterating through the collection.Every path is a single item so you need to call Add(path),not AddRange() which adds an array to the list items.You could use AddRange for the string[] filePaths array.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Add`,not `AddRange`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct; use `Add` instead of `AddRange`, and remove the `Environment.NewLine`.

There are other possible approaches:

- `AddRange` is used to add multiple items at once. So you could do that instead of the loop:

  ```
  listBox2.Items.AddRange(filePaths);
  ```
- You could also use data binding:

  ```
  listBox2.DataSource = filePaths;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
listBox2.Items.Add(path);
```

Or the following:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"folder");
listBox2.Items.AddRange(filePaths);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you this answer: [How to implement glob in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398518/how-to-implement-glob-in-c)

Comment: How is it related to the question?

Comment: It's the same question, using Glob technique you can lists all directories or files and put them to the container you want.