# find a file name knowing only the extension name

Tags: c#, file, console

I am trying to verify if a file exist in a c# console program. The only thing is that the file can have any name.

The only thing that I know is the file extension and there can only be one file of this extension. How can I verify if it exist and then use it whatever the name is?

Comment: In PHP i would use glob() for matching filename. For example if your extension is .myext you could simply match *.myext and get a list of filenames. Then you can use the first. In this question somebody asked how to implement glob in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398518/how-to-implement-glob-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you know the folder that the file will exist in?

Comment: in the assignement the folder and filename can be specified by the user but there is still a default value for both of them

Comment: assignment folder? is this homework? we shouldn't be doing your homework for you.

Comment: the assignment is way more than just this. And also we have not seen anything on files before we got this assignment because we are in the end of what we call a "session" in our scholar system and there was one more graded assignement to be done. The final exams being next week we are on our own to figure it out about files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using `Directory.GetFiles()` is that is walks the entire filesystem first, then returns all matches as an array. **Even** if the very first file examined is the one and only match, it still walks the entire filesystem from the specified root before returning the one match.

Instead, use `EnumerateFiles()` to do a lazy walk, stopping when the first match is encountered, thus:

```
DirectoryInfo root        = new DirectoryInfo( @"C:\" ) ;
string        pattern     = "*.DesiredFileExtension" ;
FileInfo      desiredFile = root.EnumerateFiles( pattern , SearchOption.AllDirectories )
                                .First()
                                ;
```

It will throw an exception if the file's not found. Use `FirstOrDefault()` to get a `null` value instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.directory.getfiles%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) static method:

```
var fileMatches = Directory.GetFiles("folder to start search in", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
if (fileMatches.Length == 1)
{
    //my file was found
    //fileMatches[0] contains the path to my file
}
```

Note that with the SearchOption enum you can specify just the current folder or to search recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.ext").Any())
{
   var file = Directory.GetFiles(path, ".ext").First();
}
```

Comment: this requires an extra bit of code to actually get the file name (which is unknown - only the extension is known).

Answer (score 1):

```
  string extension = "txt";
  string dir = @"C:\";

  var file = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*." + extension).FirstOrDefault();

  if (file != null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(file);
  }
```

If the file does not exist directly under 'dir', you will need to use SearchOption.AllDirectories for Directory.GetFiles